# How can I sort items in my PokéBag?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

In older versions of Pokémon (on the Gameboy), it was possible to sort items (I believe by pressing <kbd>Select</kbd>) which would put potions etc at the top of my bag. Is it possible to sort items in Pokémon Uranium? There is a key-binding in options for *Registered/Sort* which defaults to <kbd>F5</kbd> which I've tried pressing in my bag and nothing appears to happen. I've also tried pressing it on an item and then pressing it again on another item but nothing happens.

Although I've rebound my *Sort* key, I tried resetting to defaults and nothing happens. The only two bits of information I can find are two reddit posts ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonuranium/comments/4yekxz/is_there_a_way_to_sort_your_bag/) and [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonuranium/comments/4y49rf/issues_with_sorting_items_in_bag/)) which only appear to indicate to use the key mentioned, and that it's maybe a bug but some people appear to have it working. Both of these posts are a fortnight old.

Can items be sorted or is there some bug at the moment?

Comment: FWIW, I think select on the GBC games actually would let you move items around individually, swapping the places of whatever two items you chose.

Comment: Yeah I might be thinking one of the later generations I played briefly. I seem to recall being able to sort the TMs in order, and always have Potions then Super Potions at the top, but perhaps I just swapped everything individually :|

Comment: Well in more recent games (don't quote me on this but I think it started with 3rd gen... Possibly just FR/LG) it sorted by item type in different "pockets."